# Userform visible when worksheet active

Tags: visible, userform

is it posible to have a Userform visible when the worksheet is active.
In other words: When I'm filling cells in an sheet the userform I made must remain visible.

With kind regards Wouter.
(Dutch)

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do it. Add the following code in `Workbook_open()` event under `Thisworkbook` section if you want the form to appear on startup and always.

```
userformname.Show vbModeless
```

You will be able to enter values in the cell and view the form as well

**NOTE :**
The downfall of this method is that the form will be open irrespective of workbooks/worksheets. For example if you open an another workbook, the form will still be available on screen

BUT it serves your purpose. You can have the form displayed and work on your cell.